# Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\enginepoker2\resources\views\pages\player_edit.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm beginner in laravel, when I put stats table in blade I got this warning

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\enginepoker2\resources\views\pages\player_edit.blade.php)

this is in model Player

```
class Player extends Model
{
    protected $player = 'players'; 

    public function stats()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Stat::class, 'player');
    }
}
```

this is in Stat model

```
class Stat extends Model
{
    protected $stat = 'stats';
}
```

this is in player Controller

```
use App\Stat;
use App\Player;
use App\dealers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class botsController extends Controller
{
public function edit(Player $player, Stat $stat, dealers $dealer)
    {
        return view('pages.player_edit', compact('player', 'stat', 'dealer'));
    }
}
```

this is in route

```
Route::get('/index/bots/id={player}/edit', 'botsController@edit')->name('editBot');
```

this is in player_edit.blade that i get warning of non-object

```
<p>
   <span style="display: inline-block; min-width: 150px;">Rank</span>
   <span class="badge black">{{ $player->stats->rank }}</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this "Trying to get property of non-object" error is occurred while trying to access an array as an object. 
Make sure all the retrieved data from table are not array.

Comment: can you tell me which one must be change in this code

Comment: make sure you're not using a foreach or forelse to loop through the results you're returning from the database. I had same issues but got it fixed.

Comment: how  to get data from another ForeignKey, like $data->tbl9->FKfromtbl9->name ?

Comment: @JuMa Please go through Laravel Eloquent and understand the concepts. Then define the relationship in Model and you'll be able to access related table columns. Read more here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#retrieving-intermediate-table-columns

Answer (score 0):

check database is filled with values some values
in my case Trying to get property of non-object this error is due to my database is emppty